# Object from comma separated string using linq

Tags: c#, linq, csv, linq-to-objects

Finally getting around to learning LINQ. I want to convert the strings to objects. I know there are other ways, but I want to see how it's done using LINQ. This is the best way I've come up with:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string [] lines = new string[2];
        lines[0] = "John, 12345, true";
        lines[1] = "Miles, 45678, true";

        var o = from x in lines
                select new {
                    name = x.Split(',')[0],
                    zip  = Int32.Parse(x.Split(',')[1]),
                    status = bool.Parse(x.Split(',')[2])
                };
        foreach (var p in o) {
            Console.WriteLine(p.name + " - " + p.zip + ", - " + p.status);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there a better way without using all those `Split()`s? Here's a fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/RSY48R.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at LinqToCSV project, https://github.com/mperdeck/LINQtoCSV

Comment: this feels a bit like a  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code is working, and it is simply asking for a general code review.

Comment: Fair enough. In the future I will use codereview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string [] lines = new string[2];
        lines[0] = "John, 12345, true";
        lines[1] = "Miles, 45678, true";

        var o = from x in lines
                let eachLine = x.Split(',')
                select new {
                    name = eachLine[0],
                    zip  = Int32.Parse(eachLine[1]),
                    status = bool.Parse(eachLine[2])
                };
        foreach (var p in o) {
            Console.WriteLine(p.name + " - " + p.zip + ", - " + p.status);
        }
    }
}
```

I always think a `let` is always cleaner here. I don't think there is a nicer way other than the `split`, looks ok to me.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string [] lines = new string[2];
        lines[0] = "John, 12345, true";
        lines[1] = "Miles, 45678, true";

        var o = from line in 
                    (
                        from inner in lines
                        select inner.Split(',')
                    )
                select new {
                    name = line[0],
                    zip  = Int32.Parse(line[1]),
                    status = bool.Parse(line[2])
                };
        foreach (var p in o) {
            Console.WriteLine(p.name + " - " + p.zip + ", - " + p.status);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way of doing it is with an inner select [@Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961113/habib) has show the 'fluent' way of doing this below, this is the query version, which I think makes it easier to see wat is going on.

Enjoy your journey into LINQ!

If you can get a copy of Jon Skeet's ['C# In Depth'](http://csharpindepth.com/), the section on LINQ is absolutely brilliant. As is the rest of the book.

Comment: instead of using `let` you can have nested selects, which would be more cleaner

Comment: Downvoter, would you elaborate maybe?

Comment: @Tarec, I did in my above comment

Comment: @NewHire You're downvoting a good answer, because there's alternate way to solve the problem? That's not how voting system work on SO. The downvote button says "this answer is not useful". How is that answer not useful?

Comment: Let should be used in unavoidable situation, and I don't think this is a place for such situation. Just doesn't seem like a good practice. And for somebody trying to learn LINQ it may lead them using `let` unnecessarily.

Comment: Have updated my answer to include both, in a different way than the other answers in the post. Hope this helps guys :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = lines.Select(r => r.Split(','))
                   .Select(t => new
                       {
                           name = t[0],
                           zip = int.Parse(t[1]),
                           status = bool.Parse(t[2])
                       });
foreach (var p in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.name + " - " + p.zip + ", - " + p.status);
}
```

And you will get:

```
John - 12345, - True
Miles - 45678, - True
```

Comment: I will vote for   let clause  it's a more clean way to do it